# Lettrine: Put a letter lowercase in Lyx

Tags: lyx, lettrine

I use Lyx 2.1, document class : report.
I inserts a "lettrine", the letter that follows in uppercase, I want this letter to be lowercase.
[image]

Code :

```
\begin{onehalfspace}
\lettrine{F} ace
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `lettrine` documentation:

> Adding \usepackage{lettrine} in the preamble of a document defines the
>   command \lettrine, the simplest use of which is
>   \lettrine{}{}. It produces a dropped capital  (2
>   lines high), followed by  typeset in small caps, and the rest of
>   the paragraph is wrapped around the dropped capital.

Do `\lettrine{F}{}ace` in order to have no text in small caps.